# Please check my proof for $N$ is infinite

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> DEFINITION 1:  A set $S$ is *finite*  if there is a bijection from the set $[n]=\left\{ 1, ..., n \right\} \text{for some } n\in N$
>   to $S$.  A set is *infinite* if its not finite.

Claim : $\nexists g:[n]\to A$ an injection, where $A\subsetneq [n]\;\forall 
n\in N$

Proof of claim : Let $P(n) $ be the statement  $\nexists g:[n]\to A$ an injection, where $A\subsetneq [n]\;\forall 
n\in N$

$P(1)$ true as $\nexists g:[1]\to A $ a function, where $A\subsetneq[1] (=\phi)$

Assume $P(n)$ to be true.

Consider for $P(n+1)$ : Let $A\subsetneq [n+1]$

if $\exists g:[n+1]\to A$ an injection then

Case $1.$ $n+1\in rng(g)$

Case $1.1$ if $g(n+1)=n+1$, then $g_{[n]}$, the restriction of $g$ on $[n]$ is injection from $[n]$ to $A\setminus\{n+1\}\subsetneq [n]$, which is a contradiction to induction hypothesis.

Case $1.2$ if $g(n+1)\neq n+1$, suppose $g(i)=n+1$ and $g(n+1)=j$ then we can always interchange the value of $g$ at $i$ and $n+1$ to go back to case $1.1$ and conclude contradiction.

Case $2.$ $n+1 \notin rng(g)$ then the injection $g_{[n]}:[n]\to A\setminus\{g(n+1)\}\subsetneq [n]$ again leads to contradiction.

Back to main proof:

Since every finite set of cardinality $m$ is in bijective correspondence to $[m]$, we conclude by our above claim that there can not exist an injection from a finite set to its proper subset.

Now, on contrary, suppose $N$ is finite 
$\Rightarrow \exists f:N\to[n]$ for some $n\in N$

But $[n]\subsetneq N$ leading to contradiction. Hence, $N$ can't be finite. So $N$ is infinite.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: @PeterForeman That statement itself ("Every finite [subset of $\mathbb{N}$] has a largest element") requires proof, though.

Comment: @PeterForeman No, we have to stick to the above definition. This definition is most basic in counting. So saying $N$ has no largest element is a corollary which follows from the above theorem, not the other way around

Comment: "saying  has no largest element is a corollary which follows from the above theorem" That's not accurate: that $N$ has no largest element does not follow from the theorem above, but rather from its definition via a different argument. (Imagine if we'd replaced "$N$" with "$\{1,2,3\}$" in the definition of finiteness - we'd still get the analogous theorem, but now there *is* a largest element.)

Comment: Put another way: what definition of $N$ are you working with? Note that you haven't actually given one in the OP.

Comment: I am only following Peano's axioms

Comment: Peano's axioms > define operations on N > ordering in N > Well ordering principle > Recursion Theorem > Counting (starting with this)