# Proving $N$ is infinite using another method

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> DEFINITION 1:  A set $S$ is *finite*  if there is a bijection from the set $[n]=\left\{ 1, ..., n \right\} \text{for some } n\in N$
>   to $S$.  A set is *infinite* if its not finite.

I have proved that

if $f:[n]\to N$ is an injection, then $\exists g:[n]\to rng(f)$ an Order Preserving map.

How can I use this to show $N$ is infinite?

This is not same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3345576/please-check-my-proof-for-n-is-infinite) since I have not used order preserving map anywhere over there.

Comment: You should include relevant or [closely related information](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3345576/272831) in your question.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Sorry I don't follow. What exactly do I need to include in this question? It's a different method than the one you linked.

Comment: It's very closely related to this one, so you ought to at least link it. This way people won't get confused that there's multiple similar questions and they will be able to gain more information as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DonThousand That post is also mine and it doesn't have any answer. And NO they are not same. I have not used order preserving map in that one

Comment: @Abhay I know they aren't the same, but asking very similar questions, when the first was not answered because it was unclear, is not following the standard accepted rules of courtesy for using this site. That's essentially exploiting the front page algorithm to get your question answered. I don't think that's acceptable.

Comment: Oh I get it now. I didn't intend to do that. But please let this question stay, as I have a feeling we can show $N$ is infinite using the result mentioned in this post

Comment: Use the fact that finite linear orders are bounded.